# R: argument is of length zero solution

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a simple list

```
s<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I want to write a loop which tests whether each value in the list is greater than the previous one.

```
for(i in 1:length(s)){
  if(s[i]<s[i-1]){
    print("ok")
  }
}
```

I get the error - **Error in if (s[i] > s[i - 1]) { : argument is of length zero**

I know the reason why this is happening - Since when it is s[1]<s[0] there is no s[0] but what is the solution?

Answer (score 4):

We need to start from 2 as `i-1` for the first iteration returns 0 and `R` indexing starts from 1

```
for(i in 2:length(s)) {if(s[i] < s[i-1]) print("ok")}
```

---

Or if we want to use from `1:length(s)` (`seq_along` is a better option compared to `1:length`), make a short-circuit (`&&` - will only evaluate the second expression if and only when the first expression is TRUE) condition at the top to skip the `if` condition for `i = 1`

```
for(i in seq_along(s)) {
     if(i > 1 && (s[i] < s[i-1])) {
        print("ok")
   }
}
```

With the OP's example, there won't be anything `print`ed as next value of 's' is always greater than current

Answer (score 3):

We can also do it with a `while` loop:

```
s <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
i <- 2
while(i <= length(s)) {
  if(s[i] > s[i - 1]) {
    print("Ok")
    i <- i + 1
  } else {
    stop("The ", i, "th element is not greater than its predecessor", call. = FALSE)
  }
}

[1] "Ok"
[1] "Ok"
[1] "Ok"
[1] "Ok"
[1] "Ok"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should know that you have `n-1` times comparisons given `s` of length `n`. If you start from the second value, you can try `seq_along(s)[-1]` as the condition in `for` loop, e.g.,

```
for (i in seq_along(s)[-1]) {
    if (s[i] > s[i - 1]) {
        print("ok")
    }
}
```

which gives

```
[1] "ok"
[1] "ok"
[1] "ok"
[1] "ok"
[1] "ok"
```

---

A shorter version is using ´diff`, e.g.,

```
> for (d in diff(s)) {
+     if (d) print("OK")
+ }
[1] "OK"
[1] "OK"
[1] "OK"
[1] "OK"
[1] "OK"
```